# Run thread with derived method from base class without using templates

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance, c++17

I'd like to achieve non-templated class just like commented one. Uncommented class will results in an compilation error `error: invalid use of non-static member function 'virtual void BaseThread::worker()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

/*
class BaseThread
{
public:
    void start()
    {
// error: invalid use of non-static member function 'virtual void BaseThread::worker()'
        thread_ = std::thread(worker);
    }

private:
    virtual void worker() = 0;

    std::thread thread_;
};
*/

template <typename Derived>
class BaseThread
{
public:
    void start()
    {
        thread_ = std::thread(Derived::worker);
    }

private:
    virtual void worker() = 0;

    std::thread thread_;
};

class DerivedThread : public BaseThread<DerivedThread>
{ 
private:
    void worker()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    DerivedThread dt;
}
```

Comment: I think both of these don't work. The template one only compiles because `start` doesn't get called.

Answer (score 3):

The point is pretty simple: You pass a member function to a thread object, but not an object which that function could be called on.

The template only *seemingly* solves this problem, as you don't instantiate it. As soon as you do so, the same problem will re-appear.

You can fix that by passing an instance as parameter:

```
thread_ = std::thread(&BaseThread::worker, this);
```

Additionally, you have to take a member function pointer via appropriate operator and class scope resolution.

Side note: As you have a virtual function, you should consider adding a virtual destructor as well, otherwise deleting a derived class via pointer to base class will fail miserably.

Don't forget to join the thread in the destructor (or wherever that appears appropriate to you) either.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler and non-templated implementation could be this.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class BaseThread
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseThread() { thread_.join(); }
    void start()
    {
        thread_ = std::thread( &BaseThread::worker , this );        
    }

protected:

    virtual void worker() = 0;

private:

    std::thread thread_;
};

class DerivedThread : public BaseThread
{

protected:

    void worker() override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived\n";
    }
};

int main()
{

    DerivedThread dt;
    DerivedThread dt2;

    dt.start();
    dt2.start();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds { 5 } );
}
```

Comment: The lambda is not necessary either, `std::thread` supports member functions as well, but you need to provide an object to call the function on...

Comment: @Klaus added the destructor

Comment: I point out that this work as long as Derived::worker dont touch any Derived data member. So its not of a great use. Otherwise when derived is destroyed, the thread keep working on Derived data member that no longer exist as the thread is being destroyed when its joined in the base class destructor (called after derived class destructor). I'm currently facing this.

Answer (score 1):

Why does this not compile? The point is that you simply didn't get the syntax right, that's all. You can not call a memberfunction without an object. A simple way to pass these to `std::thread` like this:

```
std::thread th{&ThreadBase::worker, this}
```

However, you have picked an unfortunate abstraction, which is to create a "thread" class in the first place, which requires you to derive from. Don't do that, because it mixes two concerns, which are the code being called and the thread. To some extent, this is similar to creating a file baseclass which you derive from for different file formats. The indicator for this flawed approach is that in both cases, the instance of the thread or file is not a thread or file! Think about that, an instance of `std::thread` is not a thread and an instance of `std::fstream` is not a file. Rather, these objects are objects that you can use to interact with a thread or a file, similar to how a database client is used to interact with a database.

In summary, instead of writing a class that is derived from your `BaseThread`, just write a class that does something. Don't let this class worry about whether its code is called in a thread. If you want to do that, just use `std::thread` which you already did under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Call it via static member function

```
class BaseThread
{
public:
    void start()
    {
        thread_ = std::thread(sworker, this);
    }

private:
    virtual void worker() = 0;
    static void sworker(BaseThread *t) {
        t->worker();
    }
    std::thread thread_;
};
```

Comment: `std::thread` supports member functions as well, no need for a static function. But you still have to pass some instance to the thread, just as you did for the static function.

Comment: @Aconcagua thnks